# How can I read all files line by line from a directory by using Streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a directory called Files and it has many files.I want to read these Files line by line and store them an
`List<List<String>>` .

```
./Files
 ../1.txt
 ../2.txt
 ../3.txt
 ..
 ..
```

it goes like that.

```
private List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();

List<Path> filesInFolder = Files.list(Paths.get("input"))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

records = Files.lines(Paths.get("input/1.txt"))
                .map(row -> Arrays.asList(row.split(space)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Just repeat the code for every possible filename.

Comment: what have you tried to do? Share your code and someone will help you!

Comment: "records = Files.lines(Paths.get("input/1.txt"))
                    .map(row -> Arrays.asList(row.split(space)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());" I can take only one .txt file

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible to do this without using a loop of some kind, be it an *explicit* loop that you yourself write, or an *implicit* one, used behind the scenes inside the stream.

Comment: "java: lambda body is neither value nor void compatible" getting this error @Holger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic basically is like

```java
List<List<String>> records = Files.list(Paths.get("input"))
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .flatMap(path -> Files.lines(path)
        .map(row -> Arrays.asList(row.split(" "))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But you are required to catch the `IOException` potentially thrown by `Files.lines`. Further, the stream returned by `Files.list` should be closed to release the associated resources as soon as possible.

```java
List<List<String>> records; // don't pre-initialize
try(Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("input"))) {
    records = files.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .flatMap(path -> {
            try {
                return Files.lines(path)
                    .map(row -> Arrays.asList(row.split(" ")));
            } catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
catch(IOException|UncheckedIOException ex) {
    // log the error

    // and if you want a fall-back:
    records = Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Note that the streams returned by `Files.lines` used with `flatMap` are correctly closed automatically, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)):

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

---

It’s also possible to move the `map` step from the inner stream to the outer:

```java
List<List<String>> records; // don't pre-initialize
try(Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("E:\\projects\\nbMJ\\src\\sub"))) {
    records = files.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .flatMap(path -> {
            try { return Files.lines(path); }
            catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
        })
        .map(row -> Arrays.asList(row.split(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
catch(IOException|UncheckedIOException ex) {
    // log the error

    // and if you want a fall-back:
    records = Collections.emptyList();
}
```